# TinyDNS and proper settings for SPF records

Tags: email, spf, tinydns

I've inherited a TinyDNS configuration that have following entries for **SPF**:

```
@domain.com:x.x.x.3:a::86400
@domain.com:x.x.x.103:c:10:86400

=domain.com:x.x.x.3:86400
=mail.domain.com:x.x.x.3:86400
=mail.domain.com:x.x.x.103:86400

'domain.com:v=spf1 ip4\072x.x.x.3 ip4\07231.130.96.103 ptr\072mail.domain.com +mx a -all:3600
'mail.domain.com:v=spf1 ip4\072x.x.x.3 ip4\072x.x.x.103 ptr\072mail.domain.com +mx a -all:3600
'a.mx.domain.com:v=spf1 ip4\072x.x.x.3 ip4\072x.x.x.103 ptr\072mail.domain.com +mx a -all:3600
```

This is the result from http://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html

```
SPF record lookup and validation for: domain.com

SPF records are primarily published in DNS as TXT records.

The TXT records found for your domain are:
v=spf1 ip4:x.x.x.3 ip4:x.x.x.103 ptr:mail.domain.com +mx a -all 

SPF records should also be published in DNS as type SPF records.
No type SPF records found.

Checking to see if there is a valid SPF record. 

Found v=spf1 record for domain.com: 
v=spf1 ip4:x.x.x.3 ip4:x.x.x.103 ptr:mail.domain.com +mx a -all 

evaluating...
SPF record passed validation test with pySPF (Python SPF library)!
```

I'm struggling with this from yesterday and cant figure it why this validator returns `No type SPF records found.` I see in BIND we cand define **SPF** type record with `example.com.  IN SPF "v=spf1 a -all"`, but in TinyDNS we only have **TXT** records that we set for **SPF**, maybe this is a problem?

Comment: And yes, that last line describes the problem exactly.  Make a record of type SPF that exactly mirrors the record of type TXT.

Answer (score 1):

The `SPF` RR Type is not available in all DNS server implementations, which is why the RFCs allow consumers to fallback to `TXT` record evaluation.

If TinyDNS has no `SPF` record types, your configuration is just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually enter a spf (type 99) record in tinydns format.  The trick is that you have to include the length of the data in octal format.

You can use the wizard at http://anders.com/projects/sysadmin/djbdnsRecordBuilder/#SPF to generate a generic txt (type 12) record, then just change the 12 to 99 and you have a SPF record.

Here is an example:

```
:example.com:99:\041v=spf1 ip4\072192.168.001.01/30 -all:3600
```

The first : means a generic record for example.com.  The 99 specifies record type 99.  The \041 is octal for 33, the number of characters in the data.  \072 is octal for :, count all encoded octal characters as 1 char.

Credit goes to Robert Thille for his post - http://osdir.com/ml/mail.spam.spf.help/2006-12/msg00065.html